# In BitcoinJ, do I need to run downloadBlockChain() again after adding a new key?

Tags: bitcoinj

I added a Wallet instance to PeerGroup instance and executed downloadBlockChain() method. Now if I add a key(s) to that wallet, do I have to execute downloadBlockChain() again to get a current balance including a new key or will it show a right balance automatically, assuming the new key has some balance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You must call `clearTransactions(0)` on the Wallet, followed by `downloadBlockChain()` on the PeerGroup.

BitcoinJ is a thin client, meaning it doesn't download transactions for addresses that aren't in its wallet.

https://bitcoinj.github.io/working-with-the-wallet#replaying-the-chain